# How can we proof that $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How can we proof that $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational?

I was trying with contradiction by taking $\frac xy=2^{\sqrt 2}$ but can't solve it by taking $log$ also.

Comment: Well, the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) establishes this, but I imagine this answer is rather unsatisfying.

Comment: So can it be proved?

Comment: It can be proved; I have no idea how to prove it though - I imagine it's difficult.

Comment: A proof can be found on Mark Sapir's blog: http://marksapir.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/short-proof-that-2sqrt2-is-not-rational/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is famous Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a \neq 0$, $1$ and $b$ irrational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.

Comment: So can it be proved?

Comment: @user152715 Yes, but it is very difficult theorem.

Comment: Does this have any other proof?

Comment: @user152715 I am afraid, that there no easy proof. However it is easy to obtain, that at least one of the numbers $\sqrt{2}$ and $2^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: $√2$ is irrational easy, what abt $2^{√2}$?

Comment: @user152715 I have in mind an unconstrive proof, when we even don't know, which of these numbers is irrational.

Comment: Tell me... what u have?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Are you sure you're not thinking of the $\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2}$ argument that $a^b$ can be rational with both $a$ and $b$ irrational?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this particular case if you take the log by base sqrt(2) and then change the base of logarithm to 2 you get a sort of proof of irrationality of sqrt(2) byunique factorisation problem. Just brainstorming though...

Comment: I think the person who asked the question already tried this; the problem is that you get $$\log(x)-\log(y)=\sqrt{2}\log(2)$$ from this method, which doesn't look promising.